# Fixed Menu color when changing background

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve a layout where the menu is fixed in the bottom left area of the page. Its one page where you keep scrolling and the background will go thru various colors, and the menu needs to adapt to it.

[image: Layout]

The way im achieving the layout is by doing something like this

```
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      ...
    </ul>>
  </nav>
  <div class="container1">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="container2 black-bg">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="container3">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="container4 black-bg">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

The css is basically setting the navigation to be fixed in the left bottom. The containers have a width and heigh of 100vh and i change its background using the class black-gb

```
.navigation-menu {
  position:fixed;
  width: 370px;
  height: 100vh;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.black-bg {
  background-color:black;
}
```

I have read that some of this is possible by using mix-blend-mode, although i haven't been able to figure it so far. I would prefer a pure CSS solution, not planning to support IE at all. Although if you have other approaches would appreciate them as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Can u put a link 2 codepen or something?

Comment: By the way, I liked your website! :)

Comment: Thanks!, Any ideas on the color blend stuff?